# Existence of onto Homomorphism

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, group-homomorphism, roots-of-unity

Does there exists a onto Homomorphism from $\{z\in \mathbb{C}\mid z^n=1 \text{ for some }n\in \mathbb{N}\}$ to $\mathbb{Z}_{2019}$?

I think there does not exist any onto Homomorphism. All prime subgroups whose order does not divide $2019$ must be in the kernel. Intuitively there is a lack of symmetry. But I don't whether this intuition works in infinite groups or not. If works then which property should I use here.

Comment: Where is this question from?

Comment: I was asked this in viva. I could not answer it.

Comment: Note that every element in the larger group has a 2019th root.  Use this to show that the only homomorphism is the zero map.

Comment: I think i got it. Let me update in the answer. Kindly check that.

Comment: More generally, the image of a divisible group under a homomorphism will be a divisible group, and $\mathbb{Z}_n$ is not divisible for any $n\geq 2$.

Comment: So you have given me some new topic that is worth exploring. Thank you a lot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $\phi$ be any Homomorphism.

Let $a$ be any element in the larger group G.

Then $a= e^{\frac{2\pi i k}{n}}$ for some k and n.

Now $a' = e^{\frac{2\pi i k}{2019n}}$ is also an element of G.

Now $2019.\phi(a')=0\implies \phi({a'}^{2019})=0\implies \phi(a)=0$.

Hence $\phi$ is trivial.

Comment: Yes you are right. I should have written $2019.\phi(a')$. I am editing that. Thank you .